Is it possible to back-reference the labels?
The backref option in hyperref package is useful to display where the references are cited. But this only works for \cite.
Is it possible to do something similar for \label?
A desirable realization is compatible with the showkeys and cleveref packages.
That is to say, in the box displaying the label provided by showkeys package, one adds links to the places where the corresponding label appears in \ref or \cref.
It would be extremly useful to overview the relation among the theorems.

sure it is possible but apart from texref I don't know of an implementation in this direction.

Selected back references can be done with \hypertarget and \hyperlink.  The main problem is the possibility of multiple reference locations  For returning to the last location, I advise opening and closing a new window each time.
